# Fetch data from inside Blade view

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I'm learning about Laravel. I know how to create a controller that builds an array of data from an Eloquent model, pass that array to a view and display it.

What I am trying to do is create a main view that has the header and footer information all pages use. Then I try to use a child view to display the body.

The main blade file has an include for a file that builds a dynamic navigation bar.

How can I go about retrieving data from within the include file the main blade file that's called by a child?

What I have (very abbreviated) is:

main.blade.php

```
<html>
@include('header')
<body>
@section('content')

@stop
</body>
</html>
```

home.blade.php

```
@extends('main')

@section('content')
    <h1>Home</h1>
@endsection
```

Now from the controller, I call the home.blade.php view

Can I fetch the data thats needed in the header view from INSIDE the header file rather than having to pass the data from every view I call? Or do I need to simply create a global function that I call in every controller before I call a view?

Comment: Where's the code you attempted?

Answer (score 0):

In your main page:

```
 <html>
  @include('header')
 <body>
  @yield('content')
  </body>
  </html>
```

In your view:

```
   @extends('main')

   @section('content')
    <h1>Home</h1>
   @endsection
```

Comment: That's just a re-write of what I have. I am asking how to get data to the header include file without having to pass data from the child to the parent to the include every time

Comment: Where's your code from the controller? or can you show me your code inside your header?

Answer (score 0):

The *dynamic navigation bar* you mention should come from a view composer. In this way it will be available all the time to all views.

Do a test with the following in your `routes.php` file:

```
View::composer('*', function($view)
{
    // $navBar stuff
    $view->with('navBar', $navBar);
});
```

Now `$navBar` will be available in your views.

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/views#view-composers